# What kind of component is that?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm looking for the best way to achieve a result like this (a component opening at the bottom screen with some information in it) :

[image: Facebook define price range]

Is this a modal or... ?
Is this an existing component ?

Thank you

Comment: Looks to be a modal (because of the screen darkness above it) with a slider input.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a Bottom Sheet. Google's Material Design specs talk about it here: https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html

There are a few React Native bottom sheet component implementations out there that you could try.